# Take word within 35 characters

Tags: sql-server-2008

From my database of name of places, i have to retrieve a proper word within 35 characters.

**For example**

if the column has value  velow

```
 Indian School Darsait Primary Section
```

my query should return

```
Indian School Darsait Primary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(@Name) < 36 THEN @Name
        ELSE LEFT(SUBSTRING(@Name,0,36),36-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Name,0,36)))) END;
```

Selecting first 36 characters will take care of the corner cases where the position of the last character of the last word is 35th.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is this:

```
REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(NameEnglish,0, 35 )), 35 - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(NameEnglish,0, 35 ))) ))
```